# Cloudformation: How to get SecondaryPrivateIP from an instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

in the following template can any one help me how to find the SecondryPrivateIP from an instance without creating an external networkinterface.

```
"radmachine": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
  "Properties": {
    "ImageId": "ami-abcde123",
    "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
    "KeyName": "radkey",
    "DisableApiTermination": "false",
    "NetworkInterfaces": [{
        "AssociatePublicIpAddress": "false",
        "DeviceIndex": "0",
        "DeleteOnTermination": "true",
        "SubnetId": "123456",
        "GroupSet": "sg-56789",
        "SecondaryPrivateIpAddressCount": "1"
    }],
    "BlockDeviceMappings": [{"DeviceName": "/dev/xvda","Ebs": {"VolumeType": "gp2","DeleteOnTermination": "false","VolumeSize": "8"}}],
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Read through:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-network-interface.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/MultipleIP.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#AvailableIpPerENI

After understanding how it's supposed to work look at:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html

you are interested in:
**AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface** -> **SecondaryPrivateIpAddresses**

So basically you request that additional secondary private ips are bound to the network interface and after that you use Fn::GetAtt to retrieve the values that are given to the machine/interface when it builds.

Comment: yes we can get the secondary ip address through Fn:GetAtt but only in case when I create a NetworkInterface resource in template then later I attach it to my Instance then I can fetch it.

But Problem is with when we define the networkinterface along with an Instance